# Why is stringstream mixing up it's content in combination with char array and cout?

Tags: c++, cout, stringstream

in this minimal example there is a weird messing up between the input to a stringstream and the content of a previously used cout:

online gdb:
https://onlinegdb.com/itO69QGAE

code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const char sepa[] = {':', ' '};
const char crlf[] = {'\r', '\n'};


int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"  << endl;

    stringstream s;
    
    string test1 = "test_01";
    string test2 = "test_02";


    s << test1;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    // works as expected
    // excpecting: "test_01"
    // output: "test_01"
    
    s << sepa;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    // messing up with previous cout output
    // expecting: "test_01: "
    // output: "test_01: \nHello World"
    
    s << test2;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    // s seems to be polluted
    // expecting: "test_01: test_02"
    // output:  "test_01: \nHello Worldtest_02"
    
    s << crlf;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    // once again messing up with the cout content
    // expecting: "test_01: test_02\r\n"
    // output: "test_01: Hello Worldtest_02\r\nHello World"

    return 0;
}
```

So I am wondering why is this happing?

As it only happens when a char array is pushed into the stringstream it's likely about this... but according to the reference the stringstream's "<<"-operator can/should handle char* (what actually the name of this array stand's for).

Beside that there seems to be a (?hidden, or at least not obvious?) relation between stringstream and cout. So why does the content pollute into the stringstream?

Is there any wrong/foolish usage in this example or where is the dog buried (-> german idiom :P )?

Best regards and thanks
Damian

P.S. My question is not about "fixing" this issue like using a string instead of the char array (this will work)... it's about comprehend the internal mechanics and why this is actually happing, because for me this is just an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: With `s << sepa;` you treat `sepa` as a null-terminated string. Which it isn't, so you have *undefined behavior*. Same with `s << crlf;`. Why don't you make `sepa` and `crlf` actual strings? Or even use literal strings as in `s << ": ";` and `s << "\r\n";`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude make that an answer - also include the *practical* effect of this undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The `std::stringstream::str()` function returns a string containing *all characters previously written* into the stream, in *all previous calls* to `operator<<` (or other output functions). However it seems that you expect that only the last output operation will be returned - this is not the case.

This is analogous to how e.g. `std::cout` works: each invocation of `std::cout <<` appends the string to standard output; it does not clear the console's screen.

To achieve what you want, you either need to use a separate `std::stringstream` instance every time:

```cpp
std::stringstream s1;
s1 << test1;
std::cout << s1.str() << std::endl;

std::stringstream s2;
s2 << sepa;
std::cout << s2.str() << std::endl;
```

Or better, clear the contents of the `std::stringstream` using the single argument overload of the `str()` function:

```cpp
std::stringstream s;

s << test1;
std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;

// reset the contents of s to an empty string
s.str(""); 
s << sepa;
std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
```

The `s.str("")` call effectively discards all characters previously written into the stream.
Note, that even though `std::stringstream` contains a `clear()` function that would seem a better candidate, it's not analogous to e.g. `std::string::clear()` or `std::vector::clear()` and won't yield the effect desired in your case.

Comment: so where does "Hello World" come from?

Answer (score -1):

Here I am again,

Thanks to "Some programmer dude"'s comment I think I figured it out:

As there is no (null-)termination-symbol related to both char arrays it seems that the stringstream-`<<`-operator inserts until it stumbles over an null-terminator `'\0'`.

Either expending both arrays with a `\0`-symbol (e.g. **`const char sepa[] = {':', ' ', '\0'}`**) or terminating the length with e.g. `s << string(sepa,2)` will do the expected output.

In this specific case above the data seems to lay aligned in memory, so that the next null-terminator will be found inside the `cout << "Hello World"`-statement. As this alignment is not guaranteed, this will actually result in undefined behaviour, when the termination is missing.

So also two additional "terminating"-arrays like e.g **`const char sepa[] = {':', ' '}; char[] end_of_sepa = {'\0'};`** declared right after the mentioned arrays will result in expected output, **eventhough when the rest will be left unchanged**... but this is probably not guaranteed and depends on the internal representation in memory.

P.S. As previously written this issue is not about fixing but comprehension. So please feel free to confirm or correct my assumption.

EDIT: Corrected the bold code section.

Comment: It causes undefined behaviour -- and the behaviour is still undefined in your suggesting of adding other variables in other memory space. A good option would be to have the null terminator at the end of `sepa` itself, e.g. `char sepa[] = ": ";`